# 'Mobile viewport not set' even though I have included the meta tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, responsive-design

I'm trying to build a responsive rails application. When I browser wank (manually adjust the browser), the application appears to be responsive. However, when I view the application from the browser console, it's not responsive.

When I run Google's Mobile friendly test, it reads "mobile viewport not set', even though i've included the following meta tag in the [application.html.erb](https://github.com/sokocha/LegalEagle/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb): `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

I'm using

- Rails 3.2.17
- ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166)    [x86_64-darwin14.0]
- Bootstrap (download from Bootstrapwebsite, not a gem)
- Heroku

How do i set the Mobile View Port?

Comment: _"When I browser wank..."_??

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post the the browser rendered page source up to and including to the viewport line.

Comment: @ValAsensio I included the link to the application.html.erb in my original question. Here's the link: https://github.com/sokocha/LegalEagle/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb                                                                                                            This file includes the <head> <meta> tags. Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: I was curious what the page source is in the browser. That's what's being rendered by the browser. Once you look at that, it might be easier to track back to the problem in the source code.

Comment: Have you run this test? http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Comment: Another test which will tell you if Google detects the viewport is setup -- run it and look in the results section under "User experience" : https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: Still not detecting the viewport and I've got no clue as to why. The results of the test can be found here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=legal9ja.com&tab=mobile